# no results when parsing CityGML in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am working on CityGML data right now and try to parse CityGML in Python.

To do so, I use ElementTree, which is working fine with any XML files. But whenever I try to parse the CItyGML file I don't get any results.

As one example I want to get a list with all child tags named "creationDate" in the CityGML file. **Here is the code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Gasometer.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def child_list(child):
    list_child = list(tree.iter(child))
    return list_child

date = child_list('creationDate')
print (date)
```

I only get an empty list [].

**Here is the the very first part of the CityGML file (the "creationDate"-tag you can find at the end):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CityModel>
  <cityObjectMember>
    <bldg:Building gml:id="UUID_899cac3f-e0b6-41e6-ae30-a91ce51d6d95">
      <gml:description>Wohnblock in geschlossener Bauweise</gml:description>
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs,crs:EPSG::3068,crs:EPSG::5783" srsDimension="3">
          <gml:lowerCorner>21549.6537889055 17204.3479916992 38.939998626709</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>21570.6420902953 17225.660050148 60.6840192923434</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <creationDate>2014-03-28</creationDate>
```

This appears not only when I try to get lists of child tags. I can't print any attributes or tag names. It looks like the way I parse the file is wrong. I hope somebody can help me out with my problem and tell me what I should do! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an old post I'll just leave this here in case someone else might need it.
To parse CityGML try the following code, it should help getting a general idea how to fetch the information.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def loadfile():
    tree = ET.parse('filename')
    root = tree.getroot()

    for envelope in root.iter('{http://www.opengis.net/gml}Envelope'):
        print "ENV tag", envelope.tag
        print "ENV attrib", envelope.attrib
        print "ENV text", envelope.text

        lCorner = envelope.find('{http://www.opengis.net/gml}lowerCorner').text
        uCorner = envelope.find('{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner').text

        print "lC",lCorner 
        print "uC",uCorner

if __name__== "__main__":
    loadfile()
```

To get the srsName try following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def loadfile():
    tree = ET.parse('filename')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for envelope in root.iter('{http://www.opengis.net/gml}Envelope'):
        key = envelope.attrib
        srsName = key.get('srsName')
        print "SRS Name: ", srsName

if __name__== "__main__":
    loadfile()
```

I hope this helps you or anyone else who might try parsing CityGML with ElementTree.